# I insert a background-image in my HTML page but it does not show

Tags: html, css, background-image

I write the following HTML code, with a jpg image inserted, but why doesn't the image appear after the page rendering?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        div.image {
            background-image: url("images/bg1.jpg");
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="text1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus, iste?</p>
    <div class="image"></div> 
    <div class="text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeYfu.png)

Comment: The div with class image has zero width and height so it doesn't show. Are you wanting to put the image in between the two text divs or are you wanting it to be a background to one of them only or to both of them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a `div` spans full-width of its container, but has zero height unless there is some content inside it. Currently your `div.image` has zero height. Specify a height to `div.image` with something like `height: 100px` or put a child element in it.

Comment: thanks for your help.I tried your solutions. all of them worked for me except putting a child element in div.image

Answer (score 0):

you should give `HTML`, `BODY` and `div.image` a `min-height: 100vh`, then your background image should also be visible.

If you really want it to serve as a website background, you should also set the `position: absolute; top:0;left:0`.

Comment: thank you. first I gave them to html , body and div.image so my background image became visible.then I tried your second suggestion for wbsite background and it disappeared again